# New option in GCC : -fsanitize=shadow-call-stack

Tags: c, gcc, callstack, sanitizer, gcc12

I have been working with the latest release of [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (GCC 12.1, released May 6, 2022).

There is a new command-line option :  `-fsanitize=shadow-call-stack`.

The documentation states:

> GCC now supports the ShadowCallStack sanitizer, which can be enabled
> using the command-line option -fsanitize=shadow-call-stack. This
> sanitizer currently only works on AArch64 targets and it requires an
> environment in which all code has been compiled with -ffixed-r18. Its
> primary initial user is the Linux kernel.

I think it could be useful for one of the projects I am working on, but I would like to make sure I understand better the exact behaviour of this option. I found the documentation a little bit lacking. Can anyone explain its behaviour?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ShadowCallStack.html

Comment: I've installed gcc 12.1 and when I try to use this option I get: sorry, unimplemented: ‘-fsanitize=shadow-call-stack’ not supported in current platform. Is there any information for which platform it should work? Because it doesn't work for x64.